# Telnet to mysql refused

Tags: mysql, telnet, iptables, ufw

My mysqlserver suddenly cannot access remoly although all configurations are correct. Here are my info:

1. I enabled ufw (3306)
   [image]
2. my mysqld.cnf
   [image]
3. and my netstat
   [image]
4. my itables -L
   [image]

But i got refused telnet connection remotely.

Please help me.

Comment: you should not use telnet to access mysql?  use a mysql client